# BarButtonItem not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

In an app Im making, Im trying to enable login/logout to twitter.  I want it so that there is a barbuttonitem that either says login if there is no current user, or logout if there is one.  I created two buttons on the storyboard, one for login and one for logout.  In the viewDidLoad(), I have this code:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil


    if twitterUser.currentUser != nil {
        print("there is a current user")

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logoutButton

    } else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = loginButton
    }
```

and it seems to work well.  The problem comes when the user actually logs in or out.  The buttons are connected to the following functions:

```
@IBAction func onLogin(sender: AnyObject) {

    let client = twitterAPI.sharedInstance

    client.login({ () -> () in

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  nil

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.logoutButton

        }) { (error: NSError) -> () in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}


    @IBAction func onLogout(sender: AnyObject) {
    twitterAPI.sharedInstance.logout()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.loginButton
}
```

After logging in the login button will disappear, but the logout button does not show up.  When logging out, the logout button disappears but the login button does not appear.  I'm not sure what would be causing this, as I use the same methods in the viewDidLoad and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Is the block passed to login() executed on the main thread?  If you print something in onLogin() and onLogout(), do you see the messages?

Comment: You might be nullifying your `self.logoutButton` and `self.loginButton`. Print a description of them before you assign them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you

```
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "barBtnAction:")
       barButton.tag = 0
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }

    @IBAction func barBtnAction(sender:UIBarButtonItem)
    {           
       let shouldLogin: Bool = sender.tag == 0 ? true : false
       if shouldLogin
       {
          //your code here
          onLogin()
       }
       else
       {
          //your code here
          onLogout()
       }
    }

  func onLogin()
  {
      barButton.title = "Logout"
      barButton.tag = 1
  }

  func onLogout()
  {
      barButton.title = "Login"
      barButton.tag = 0
  }
```

Comment: `let shouldLogin: Bool = sender.tag == 0 ? true : false`
 should just be
`let shouldLogin: Bool = sender.tag == 0`
  don't know why you added the unnecessary ternary operator

Comment: @Qunin: you can modify the code in own way.. i was just giving only sample code. If you didn't like ternary conditional statement then use if else conditional block..

Comment: My point was the ternary operator in this case does absolutely nothing, there is no need to use an if else either... that would be even worse

Comment: @Qunin: I was using ternary operator only for code readability.