# IOS: How to Reset Action of UIBarButtonItem after it has been created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have some code that creates barbuttonitem Edit and if you click it and begin editing, changes the button to Done.

When I first create the button I set its action to Edit.  However, once the user is editing, I want to change the action of the renamed button to Save.

I thought I had save firing but somewhere along the line it stopped working possibly when I added a method in the middle to enable and disable the button.

Can anyone suggest the proper way to change the action of a bar button item?

Here is my code:

```
  //code to create button which sets action to gotoEdit method
         UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoEdit)];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
        }
    -(void) gotoEdit {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
        _editButton.target = self;
        _editButton.action = @selector(save);//changes action to save method
//some other code to make a textview editable, change its background color and so forth.
       }
-(void) save {
NSLog(@"save method firing");
}
//I added the following methods at about the same time the save method stopped firing but not sure if they are related.  (Probably not but including them anyway.)
    //detect change on screen
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
        self.didChange=YES;
        [self updateSaveButton];
    }
    -(void) updateSaveButton
    {  
        self.editButton.enabled = (_didChange == TRUE);
    }
```

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36046263/3918500

Comment: for the your given code is working, the only change i notice is in the you have created local object for `UIBarButtonItem ` and in the `gotoEdit` method you are trying to get global object , the below two method has nothing to do with the save action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use a `bool` instead of adding and removing the button's action.

```
-(void) gotoEdit {
    if(!isEditing){
        // Prep for editing
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
        isEditing = true;
    }else{
        // Prep for saving
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"Edit";
        isEditing = false;
    }     
}
```

For future reference you can remove a button's selector like this:

```
[_editButton removeTarget:self 
               action:@selector(gotoEdit) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```